# Downloading zip files using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to download every country's "administrative areas" from this website: http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata.

I'm new to using the Python Selenium package, but I'm fairly certain the code below should at least download Afghanistan's data.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2) # custom location
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', '/tmp')
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'text/csv')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
driver.get("http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata")
driver.find_element_by_name('OK').click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Download').click()
```

I'm able to open other links on the same page using this method, but I can't open the "Download" link for some reason. No error message is shown after running this code. I did look at similar SO posts, but I still don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check if below code works. I've replaced your find **link by text** with **css selector**. Also, updated `text/csv` with `application/zip`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2) # custom location
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', '/tmp')
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'application/zip')


driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
driver.get("http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata")
driver.find_element_by_name('OK').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#node-39 > div > div > div > div > a > h2").click()
```

Comment: Yup, worked perfectly thanks! Any idea why my method didn't work though?

Comment: @J-Win - The **Download** text was under a **h2** tag inside link. It is probably the reason why your code didn't work.

Comment: Oh what the heck? Yes I see that now. Thanks again!

Comment: Note: If this isn't working for anyone, your zip file download might have a MIME type of `application/download` or `application/octet-stream` instead of `application/zip`

Answer (score 0):

**I recommend it for Firefox**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
options.set_preference("browser.download.dir","/data")
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/octet-stream,application/vnd.ms-excel")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=self.options)
```